# bash: pipe data into an exec'd command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a program, `sink.py`, that I want to run in a bash script (`run.sh`). `sink.py` needs data from stdin to do its job.

I'd like to feed data from another program, `source.py`, into `sink.py`. The following pipeline works fine:

```
python source.py | python sink.py
```

However, I'm looking to `exec sink.py`, so that it takes over the shell. I want to do this because I'm starting this bash script from a process manager (supervisord) and `sink.py` has all the signal handling code. So ideally I could do something like this:

```
python source.py | exec python sink.py
```

But this doesn't seem to work -- `ps` shows that `run.sh` continues to run as a parent of `sink.py`.

I tried using process substitution like this:

```
exec python sink.py < <(python source.py)
```

This is almost perfect, except the bash script appears to become a "zombie", which presumably is not a good thing:

```
 PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
1042 pts/7    S      0:00 python sink.py
1046 pts/7    Z      0:00 [run.sh] <defunct>
```

One other thought I had was to just save the output of `source.py` into a temporary file, then direct the file into `sink.py`. That almost works, except I have no way of deleting the temp file once I `exec sink.py`.

Is there any good way to accomplish this?

Comment: A zombie is just a process table entry that no parent process is `wait()`ing for (and thus reaping from the table). Who's the parent process that's running your script in the first place?

Comment: If that parent process were a shell, for instance, it would be handling `SIGCHILD`s with an appropriate `wait` call.

Comment: I am running the script from a shell as I test things out. (Eventually supervisord will run it.) When `sink.py` ends, the zombie process goes away. (Assuming "Z" and "<defunct>" indicate zombie.)

Comment: Short form: That zombie is completely harmless. Unless supervisor is an utterly awful piece of software (in which case I'd suggest replacing it with runit or DJB daemontools), it'll get properly reaped before restart, meaning no more than one at a time.

Comment: (Since a zombie is nothing but a process-table entry corresponding with a process that already exited, they use no CPU time, and only the memory needed for that one table entry, which is tiny).

Comment: Oooh. Actually, I think I may see the problem here -- it's `python source.py` that's the parent after the `exec` has finished, so it's what gets the SIGCHILD and is responsible for reaping any children. If it's not doing that, that explains why nothing happens to clear up the process table entry until after it exits (and its parent inherits, and handles, the dead child's process table record).

Comment: BTW, to be clear, in all my comments above I'm focusing in on the process-substitution approach, which is the correct one for the scenario at hand.

Comment: Interesting. I may not be understanding correctly, but it's surprising to me that `python source.py` would be the parent of anything. FWIW, it ends well before `python sink.py`. (But I guess that's obvious since it's being fed into `sink.py` via process substitution.)

Comment: sorry, `sink.py` is indeed the parent (responsible for, but not, reaping the zombie left behind by `source.py` when it exits).

Comment: the thing is, installing a general-purpose SIGCHILD handler in your Python interpreter is liable to cause other problems if you leave it there (if the `subprocess` module expects to be able to reap children it starts on its own, for instance, then removing those entries from the process table will prevent it from being able to get their exit status), so I'd avoid doing that. Personally, I'd consider just living with the zombie less trouble.

Comment: Yeah, `ps fax` definitely shows `sink.py` as the parent. So I guess the child is there because something needs to clean up the file descriptor created by the process substitution?

Comment: Exactly right. But if you just ignore it until `source.py` exits, *its* parent will handle the cleanup, or so forth until it gets inherited by PID 1, which takes care of it then.

Comment: Got it, thanks. For the moment I'll use the process substitution approach and just try to ignore the negative connotations of the word "zombie".

Comment: @JohnBollinger, ...btw, your answer looks good to me as currently amended. What's the ETA to having it undeleted? :)