# Keeping access to STDIN of a program run in the background via a FIFO

Tags: shell, docker, stdin, file-descriptor, io-redirection

So I have a docker image, containing a minecraft server. A minecraft server takes input from the STDIN, so after starting the server with `java -jar server.jar` I can feed it commands (to stop the server for example) by typing it in the console.

Ideally I want to start the server in a shellscript that looks something this:

```
#!/bin/sh

.. some initialization ..

exec java -Xmx$RAM -Xms$RAM -jar server.jar
```

This way the java executable takes over the process, so that it can be gracefully terminated when docker sends a `SIGTERM`.

The issue comes when I want to keep an artificial `STDIN`, that allows me to executes commands onto the server via another script. To do this I made a FIFO that represents the console like so:

```
rm -f console; mkfifo console
```

I'm not sure how I can redirect this `FIFO` into the process this way though. I'm reading the fifo using `cat` in a while-loop like so

```
while true; do cat console; done
```

And thought about doing something like this:

```
while true; do cat console; done | exec java -jar server.jar
```

Or something like this:

```
exec java -jar server.jar < <(while true; do cat console; done)
```

For the latter, I've looked at [bash: pipe data into an exec'd command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519379/bash-pipe-data-into-an-execd-command) which unfortunately gives me `syntax error: unexpected redirection`

I've also tried this:

```
while true; do cat console; done >&0 &

exec java -jar server.jar
```

which seems to freeze the server while it's starting.

I have no idea why all of this is not working, and I don't know how I can make it  work.

To be clear of what I want to achieve:

- Have java (the server) take over the main process
- Have a FIFO redirected to the STDIN of the server

It sounds so simple to me, but I just cannot make it happen. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the `< <(command)` syntax is not supported in /bin/sh but it is support in /bin/bash.

After switching to that, my final line is:

```
exec java -jar server.jar < <(tail -f console)
```

Sometimes you just have to accept that you have to install more dependencies..